# Do all massive stars explode?

Tags: star, black-hole, supernova

I've read a few articles written in $2008$ that some stars which have enough mass just collapse into black holes without a supernova, is this proven?

Comment: Failed supernovae are certainly possible, but the jury is still out on black holes emerging anyway: https://arxiv.org/abs/1609.01283

Comment: There are hypothesis about supernovas that were in such massive stars that the outer layers contained the blast, yet a black hole still formed in the middle.  They might have been stable for a few million years even.  I just saw [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=UgTmGFEkeZE) yesterday talking about it.  They don't have a definitive answer either, but it is a little more information about the topic.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There are a variety of models of stars collapsing into black holes without proper supernova explosions. These are often called [*failed supernovae*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Failed_supernova) or *direct collapse black holes* - although the former seems more common. Failed supernovae can happen if the initial shock wave rebounding from a collapse loses enough energy, causing it to fizzle out. Neutrinos produced in the core often supply this energy, but a small enough burst may not be enough to keep the shock going. There might then be a simple collapse.

The minimum mass for the progenitor of a failed supernova is unknown (and as Rob Jeffries pointed out, this is metallicity-dependent). Some early models (e.g. [Fryer (1999)](http://iopscience.iop.org/article/10.1086/307647/fulltext/)) found that stars above $40M_{\odot}$ could produced failed supernovae, while newer ones suggest that this could be as low as $25M_{\odot}$. This lower limit would include a sizable portion of red supergiants - which could be a possible solution to [the red supergiant problem](https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/q/16148/2153).

A number of searches, largely targeting supergiants, have been carried out. Just a few are

- [Adams et al. (2016)](https://arxiv.org/abs/1609.01283), using the Hubble Space Telescope to examine [N6946-BH1](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/N6946-BH1), a disappeared red supergiant of $25M_{\odot}$.
- [Reynolds et al. (2015)](https://arxiv.org/abs/1507.05823), looking at past Hubble data. They found one possible candidate, a $25\text{-}30M_{\odot}$ red supergiant in [NGC 3021](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NGC_3021).

So far, we have no definite confirmation that these stars were failed supernovae. However, they do seem plausible candidates, and there are many more possibilities out there. [One group proposed monitoring one million supergiants](http://iopscience.iop.org/article/10.1086/590053/meta) in an attempt to catch failed supernovae. Perhaps they'll be successful.

Comment: The recent detection of gravitational wave sources makes the production of 30 solar mass black holes necessary. These are unlikely to be produced in supernovae I think. Also worth mentioning that the direct collapse events are more likely in low-metallicity objects.

Comment: JPL just posted a few days ago a new article on N6946-BH1 and failed supernovae in general. It claims that as many as 30 percent of stars 25 solar masses or greater may collapse into black holes sans supernova.

Comment: @called2voyage That's interesting; I'll have to read that.